# Troubles installing rattle for R

Tags: r, rattle

I apologize in advance if I missed some obvious rookie mistake I did.
I tried installing rattle both through R terminal with the `install.packages` command and both with

```
wajig install r-cran-rattle
```

neither worked: In the first case it downloaded some tar.gz to a temp folder but didn't install anything, in the second one it says that is Unable to locate package r-cran-rattle.
I'm attaching some screenshot to better showcase what I tried to do and what kind of messages I'm getting:

```
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/2278/06fVvR.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3198/P28Yv1.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/1463/ZGpSGb.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/5169/aBsT1G.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/9031/IaSAyg.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/2918/thJ4Ay.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/8039/07uKDL.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/4054/NGHeoB.png
```

In the end, when I try the rattle command in R terminal it always says that it cannot find the function rattle. Thanks in advance to whoever will help me.
Best regards,
Andrea.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the query.

Rattle has installed just fine. You need to load the rattle package into the library each time you start up R using `library(rattle)`. The call to `rattle()` should then work.

In general, the steps to install Rattle (with the GUI functionality provided by RGtk2) should be:

```
$ wajig install r-recommended
$ R
> install.packages("rattle")
> install.packages("RGtk2")
> library(rattle)
> rattle()
```

A number of other packages will be automatically installed too.

To then install the latest development (but quite stable) release:

```
> install.packages("rattle", repos="https://rattle.togaware.com", type="source")
```